# Ebean ORM auto create table structure in SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, ebean

I have a following model class. It's just for testing.

```
@Entity
public class Quest {

    public static final Find<Long, Quest> find = new Find<Long, Quest>() {};

    @Id
    Long id;

    @Column(length=100)
    String name;

    //... Constructors/getters/setters
}
```

And in main method trying to connect to database:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(!AgentLoader.loadAgentFromClasspath(
        "avaje-ebeanorm-agent",
        "debug=1;packages=com.package.mmohelper.model.**")
    ) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Agent loader exception");
    }

    DataSourceConfig ds = new DataSourceConfig();
    ds.setDriver("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:data");
    ds.setUsername("");
    ds.setPassword("");
    ds.setIsolationLevel(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);

    ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();
    config.setName("Sqlite");
    config.setDdlGenerate(true);
    config.setDdlRun(true);
    config.setAutoCommitMode(true);
    config.setDefaultServer(true);
    config.setDatabasePlatform(new SQLitePlatform());
    config.getDatabasePlatform().getDbDdlSyntax().setIdentity("");
    config.setDataSourceConfig(ds);

    EbeanServer server = EbeanServerFactory.create(config);

    Quest q = new Quest(0L, "Quest1");
    q.save(); // !!! Fails here !!!
}
```

When I run it, it fails with following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: quest)]

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: quest)
```

So, question is: what's wrong? Why does table won't create automatically? What if I want to create database 'on-the-fly'? I should use plain JDBC for creating table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "quest")
public class Quest
```